# application-defined or object-defined error when setting range variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Range` variable and a separate workbook which I try to fill with values. I use `TheRange` for it, first setting it to the range of `clientsColl.Count` rows and 1000 columns.

```
Dim TheRange As Range

With resultWorkbook.Worksheets("matrix_random")

    Set TheRange = _
        .Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(clientsColl.Count, _
                                     1000)))

...
End With
```

However, I keep getting this error, can't figure out why..

> Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: you need the little `.` for the `Cells`, try `.Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(1000, clientsColl.Count)))` , and you have the `Rows` and `Columns` switched in the second `Cells`

Comment: Where did you define `clientsColl` ?

Comment: @Shai Rado, Thank you, kind person! Saved me hours!!

Comment: What is the value of `clientsColl.Count`

Comment: @ShaiRado You have eagle's eyes. Good catch. :)

Comment: @sktneer LOL :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Ths is where experience plays it's role. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for future users to get the an answer.

You need to qualify your `.Cells` with the `With resultWorkbook.Worksheets("matrix_random")` statement.

Also, the second `Cells` has `Rows` and `Columns` swapped.

**Code**

```
Dim TheRange As Range

With resultWorkbook.Worksheets("matrix_random")
    Set TheRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(1000, clientsColl.Count)) '<-- you have 1 "extra" closing bracket
End With
```

Comment: Good catch. plus 1